# How Can I Find Which Process is Displaying a Randomly Appearing Window?

Tags: vbscript, scripting

I have a user who randomly gets a Script Error box (shown below) which doesn't indicate what program is having the issue.  It'll popup multiple times a day.  Any ideas on how to determine which program is failing?  He can't determine any consistency about when they pop up.

[image: Script Error Pic]

Comment: What is their default web browser? I would bet that you will find that is the process that is throwing the error. This error is being generated by a web page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the pop up window is visible in the task manager (in the application tab) then you can right click on it and select "Go To Process" that will select the process that the window is attached to.